# Trigger existing Glue Job with Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-glue

I have been trying to trigger an existing Glue job with Airflow. I've been using:

```
GlueJobOperator(
    job_name =glue_job_name,
    region_name = region_name,
    iam_role_name = glue_iam_role,
    task_id = 'glue_job_step',
    dag = dag,
    s3_bucket=bucket_name
    )
```

It fails with:

```
[2023-03-24, 10:56:53 UTC] {glue.py:286} INFO - Checking if job already exists: ingest_zoho_books_bills
[2023-03-24, 10:56:54 UTC] {glue.py:311} INFO - Updating job: job_name
[2023-03-24, 10:56:54 UTC] {glue.py:171} ERROR - Failed to run aws glue job, error: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter JobUpdate.Command.ScriptLocation, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I don't know the solution, but your code is trying to create new Glue job, not run an existing one. That's why it's complaining you didn't tell it where in S3 to put the script.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dommondke said, in versions of apache-airflow-providers-amazon before 7.4, the GlueJobOperator forces updates of an existing Glue Job, so you can't just trigger an existing glue job without passing in the script location and arguments if it takes in any.

If you want to avoid the forced update of the job and just want to submit it as is, you'd have to upgrade apache-airflow-providers-amazon to a version of 7.4 or higher. Or, you can just go directly to the [source here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-amazon/7.4.0/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py) and implement it yourself by copying it